# Android: how to debug application on Nexus One

Tags: android, android-emulator

The desktop application emulator works fine.
Settings > Applications > Development > USB debugging is checked.
The "USB debugging connected" alert is displayed on the Nexus One when the USB cable is attached but I can't seem to get the debugger to run the code on it.
Is there something else I need to do to get the debugger to work on the device?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sometimes you need to manually select the run target.

in Eclipse:

> 1. Run->Run Configurations
> 2. Select your project
> 3. in the Android tab    select Launch and pick your Activity
> 4. in the Target tab    select Manual
> 5. Apply
> 6. Run
> 7. Choose your device

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Windows, make sure you have the usb driver installed. 
Then go into the directory of your Android SDK / tools via command line (`cmd`), type "`adb devices`" in the command line to see if your device appears.

Comment: "adb devices" returns the error message "adb is not recoginized" but "Android Composite ADB Interface" is in Device manager.

Comment: hm I meant typing 'adb devices' in the windows command line when you're in the tools directory of the SDK. I didn't know that you meant  within Eclipse, but nevermind, I see you got it working already :)